# handling event bubling in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

iam having links as shown below

```
<a item='1' href='javascript:void(0)'><img class='icon1' /><span>text1</span></a>
<a item='1' href='javascript:void(0)'><img class='icon2' /><span>text2</span></a>
<a item='1' href='javascript:void(0)'><img class='icon3' /><span>text3</span></a>
<a item='1' href='javascript:void(0)'><img class='icon4' /><span>text4</span></a>


$(function(){
$('a').click(_handleClick);
});

function _handleClick(e)
{
var _item=$(e.target).attr('item');
// do something with _item variable
}
```

// now my problem is when user clicks on image 'e' received in _handleClick is image so i can't read attr='item' so how can bubble the event to read that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do any handling of event bubbling at all since the 'a' element that has the event handler attached, also stores the 'item' attribute. In that case, you just use 'this' to refer to the item with the click event, and $(this).attr('item') will retrieve the value of 'item'.

This line:

```
var _item=$(e.target).attr('item');
```

should be:

```
var _item=$(this).attr('item');
```

**EDIT: Clarified the first sentence, and added the following info:**

To clarify, event bubbling is automatic in jQuery. If you click on an element's child, the event will bubble all the way up to the top, firing events as it goes.

There are times when you need to stop the firing with `event.stopPropagation()`.

There are other times where it comes in handy. For example, consider a 'div' that has 100 children, all of which should receive the same click event. Instead of consuming all the resource that it requires to maintain event handlers for those 100 children, you could just assign 1 click event to the parent, then use event.target to determine which one was actually clicked.

Another nice thing about this approach, is that you don't have to use live() when dynamically adding additional children to that parent. Since they all fire the parent's click event because of bubbling, they are ready to go.

Comment: But there are two elements inside the anchor tag, and those are likely to be the actual recipients of the event. The other answer given that looks for the parent anchor is closer, though it's not impossible for a click to "poke through" to the anchor.

Comment: @Pointy - The event is attached to the 'a' element. Irrespective of what the actual target is, the event handler is called on the 'a'. It is event bubbling that causes this. The first sentence of my answer is a little deceiving, so I'll tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of doing the click target directly:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    var _item = $(this).attr('item');
    // do something with _item variable        
  });
});
```

Though the `click` event is fired on all parent elements, the `e.target` is still the source of the click, the original deepest child you clicked on...jQuery with the `$(this)` handles that, no need to worry which child element below fired it.

Answer (score 0):

`var _item=$(e.target).parents('a').attr('item');`

Comment: This is a better answer, though it might not be impossible for the event to be directly triggered on the anchor tag. I think it'd be best to check to see if the target element is the anchor, and if not then use "parents('a')" to find it.

Comment: No need to reflect on parents of the target, since the event will automatically bubble up to the same element that has the 'item' attribute.